# Visual Studio 2008 web express: create new SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I just downloaded [Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) and I want to create a local [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) database so I can start local development.

How do I get started? How do I create a local SQL Server database?

Comment: what do you want me to do if the answer provided does not resolve my issue? Should I accept no matter what ???? I do accept the answers if they resolve my issue...

Comment: I have a hard time believing that only in 16 of 62 questions, this was the case.....

Comment: I think SQL express is installed with VS express but I'm not sure; usually the *management studio* isn't installed by default so you'll have to download this separately. However, this question smells like it should be on superuser.com or serverfault.com - no?

Answer (score 1):

You can either create one in code, or download the [management tools](http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/download/) and do it through the UI. If all you downloaded was the runtime these are not included.

Answer (score 1):

This walk through, [Creating a SQL Server Express Database File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763(VS.80).aspx)   should help you out some.

If you have time and further questions about Visual Studio Web Developer Express you can also watch videos at: [Visual Web Developer Express - Easy to Learn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/express/aa700799.aspx) and [Building Web Applications with Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/#VisualWebDeveloper).

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project in VS2008 which is a database solution.